# IndexOf over a nested array response graph returning just []

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql

I am trying to filter some articles from a graphql response, by articleTag. Se my structure below:

```
    {
        "id": "41744081",
        "articleTitle": "text",
        "articleContent": "text",
        "categoryName": { "categoryName": "Company", "id": "38775744" },
        "articleTags": [
            { "articleTag": "event", "id": "37056861" },
            { "articleTag": "car", "id": "37052481" },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "41754317",
        "articleTitle": "text",
        "articleContent": "text",
        "categoryName": { "categoryName": "Sales and Martketing", "id": "38775763" },
        "articleTags": [{ "articleTag": "technology", "id": "37056753" }]
    },
...
```

But when applying my function:

```
 notificationFiltered () {
        var articleResponse = this.response.allArticles;
        var routeParam =  this.$route.params.tagName; //contains the id of the tag
   
       const filteredTag = articleResponse.filter((item) => {
             return (item.articleTags.indexOf(routeParam) >= 0);
       });
         console.log(filteredTag);
    },
```

When I'm  "console.log" the result I get only a "[]". Not sure if is related with the way of query is being render, in the API I get the same formation but with this slightly difference

```
{
"data": {
"allArticles": [... the specify structure above]  
}
}
```

while printing that with vue {{response.allArticles}} I just get the first structure, I think it shouldn't matter?

Thanks in advance for the advice

Comment: `articleTags` is not an array of simple values, `indexOf` with simple arg won't work

Comment: `articleTags` contains objects, the tag id can't be found from that array. Use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead of `indexOf`: `return item.articleTags.findIndex(obj => obj.id === routeParam) > -1;`.

Comment: @Teemu thank you very much, this quite to the same suggestion with findIndex below, but both also works just different logic  : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use `indexOf` for array of objects to find a *matching* object - only strict equality is needed, and that's hard to get in the reference land. Consider this:

```
const objs = [
    { foo: 'bar' }, 
    { foo: 'baz' }, 
    { foo: 'foo' } // whatever
];
const needle = { foo: 'baz' };
objs.indexOf(needle);
// -1
```

What? Yes, there's an object looking exactly like `needle` in that array - but it's **a different object**:

```
objs[1] === needle; // false
```

That's why indexOf just goes past that one - and gives out -1, a "not found" result.

What you should be able to use in this case is `findIndex`. Still you need to build the predicate to have a match. For example:

```
const objs = [
    { foo: 'bar' }, 
    { foo: 'baz' }, 
    { foo: 'foo' }
];
const needle = { foo: 'baz' };
objs.findIndex(el => JSON.stringify(el) === JSON.stringify(needle)); 
// 1
```

In this example, comparing results of JSON.stringify in the predicate function is a poor man's [_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) - just to illustrate the concept. What you should consider actually using in your code is either _.isEqual itself, or similar function available in toolkit of your choice.

Alternatively, you can just check for specific fields' values:

```
objs.findIndex(el => el.foo === needle.foo); // still 1
```

This will apparently find objects even if their other properties do not match though.

Comment: Thank you for take the time of writing a detailed explanation, this is always helpful when you are trying to understand and learning : )